# Constructor call to wpf usercontrol (with path and geometry) taking 4 secs

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have to create an user control and pass it to a modal dialog:

```
var control = new ThresholdWarningOverrideModalUserControl(); //The problem is this line of code not after that

var dialog = new ModalDialog(control, this.ViewModelInstance);
dialog.ShowDialog();
```

Now the first line of code takes 4 - 5 seconds to execute. But it is not even rendering anything. However this user control draws using path.

The usercontrol constructor is simple and all the code is in xaml:

```
 public ThresholdWarningOverrideModalUserControl()
 {
       this.InitializeComponent();
 }
```

If I remove the drawing paths the control loads quickly. The paths have binding and converters to imagebrush and objects.

Comment: What does the constructor of `ThresholdWarningOverrideModalUserControl` look like? Post the code...

Comment: Where does ModalDialog come from?  I am not finding it in WPF.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969773(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The problem is not with ModalDialog .. its a custom window.

Comment: If you reduce the draw path does the time come down?  So you are passing the control to a Window (that is evoked as a modal dialog).

Comment: Yes I am passing the user control to another window. Yes if I reduce the drawpath the control loads quickly.

Comment: show the XAML code maybe so we can recreate the issue?  You should have 5 million things in the XAML, calling InitializeComponent() is going to load your XAML and build a visual tree still.  So even though you're not explicitly showing it, its loading the components of the view.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are images inside drawpath and when I load the images beforehand and store them as properties in viewmodel and then supply the viewmodel to the control in constructor it loads in 100 ms.